# Magento2: Add Manufacturer image to details page

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, manufacturer

In Magento 2.1, I need to add manufacturer's logo in product detail page. Now, I added an attribute `manufacturer` from the backend.

I did that by going to `Stores -> Attribute set` then choosing Default. then there was two Unassigned Attributes, Color and Manufacturer. I dragged manufacturer into Product Details under Groups. Now I have a dropdown list at the backend's product catalog page (Product -> catalog -> edit/add the product ).

Now I need to implement when I choose a manufacturer from that dropdown, in that product's, product detail page manufacturer image should be displayed.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've accomplished this without creating a module. **Hope this may help somebody**

1. I created a custom product attribute. which allows the user to choose a manufacturer from the dropdown list.
2. I get image from app->design>[my vendor]->[my theme]->web->images->products, and image name will be equal to name selected from above dropdown.
3. Added layout in XML where I need this image should be.
4. used phtml file to locate images and display.

**1.**

From admin menu, Stores->Attributes->product

Create a new attribute. `Default Label(your name)`, `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner(dropdown)`, `Values Required(No)`. under `Manage Options (Values of Your Attribute)` you can add your options.

**2.**

You can choose any location as you need.

**3.**

This could be different for your needs,

```
<referenceContainer name="product.details.section" >
<container name="brand.logo" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="right-brand" before="-">
     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="customBrandLogo" template="product/view/custombrandlogo.phtml"/>
</container>
```

**4.**

in my case, phtml file is custombrandlogo.phtml located at `Magento_Catalog->templates->product->view`

*I get manufacturer name from backend menu,*

```
<?php 
 $_product = $this->getProduct();
 $manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
 $manufacturerId = $_product->getManufacturer(); 
//php close tag will be at the end
```

*I convert the name into lowercase and replace underscores with spaces.*

```
$manufacturerName= strtolower($manufacturerName);
```

$manufacturerName=str_replace(' ', '_',$manufacturerName);

*I get image path*

```
$imgPath=$this->getViewFileUrl("{$imgPath}/{$manufacturerName}" ); 

//php tag is closed?>
```

_Finally display an image with `img` tag.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo  $imgPath ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $manufacturerName; ?>" /></a>
```

**I hardcoded image extension as .png**

Answer (score 2):

Create a module for this task.

Store all your Manufacturer images at path `Company/Module/view/frontend/web/images/` with the exact name of menufacturer.

Then, you need to override template file for the product page and get Manufacturer Label in that template file:

```
$menufacturer = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Then, you can insert image like this:

```
<img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Company_Module::images/' . $menufacturer . '.png'); ?>' alt="<?php echo $menufacturer ?>" width="30" height="25">
```

Comment: Hi,  I am still a newbie. could you provide more details and files/code if you have any?

Comment: hey @Joey, I don't have the code ready to use. You can do it by yourself quite easily.

Comment: I've accomplished this without creating a module. thanks for your help

Comment: Joey can you share how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php/***********Display Brand Attribute in detail page************/?>

            <?php
            if($_product->getManufacturer()){
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category

                $brand_value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                $brand_id = $_product->getManufacturer();
                $curnt_cat_url = $category->getUrl();
                $brandId = '?manufacturer='.$brand_id;

                $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $swatchHelper=$om->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media");
                $swatchCollection = $om->create('Magento\Swatches\Model\ResourceModel\Swatch\Collection');
                $swatchCollection->addFieldtoFilter('option_id',$brand_id);
                $item=$swatchCollection->getFirstItem();
                $ThumbImage =  $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_thumb', $item->getValue());
                $SwatchImage = $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_image', $item->getValue());

                ?>

                <div class="brand_bg">
                    <a href="<?php echo $curnt_cat_url.$brandId; ?>" title="<?php echo $brand_value; ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $ThumbImage; ?>"></a>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php/***********End Brand Attribute************/?>
```